Kendo UI Rich Text Editor localization: Paragraph and Heading not translated
We are starting to use Kendo UI for Vue HTML Editor for an application with support for multiple languages.
I have noticed it would be nice to translate Paragraph and Heading. Currently, Paragraph and Heading are in English and they are not listed in my current version as translatable items (Kendo UI Vue 4.3.2).
I have searched for "Paragraph" in the forums and here to no avail.
As a Spanish speaker, I would expect to format my HTML using "Párrafo" instead of "Paragraph" and "Encabezado 1" instead of "Heading 1".

You can customize the Editor element's formatting tool dropdown items at initialization, using the tools configuration option, like this:
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  tools: [{
    name: "formatting",
    items: [
      {text: "Párrafo", value: "p"},
      {text: "Cotización", value: "blockquote"},
      {text: "Encabezado 1", value: "h1"}
    ]
  }]
});

Where the tools array is the list of tools, you want to display. In this array, you can add the keys of the default tools, or can be configured one-by-one, or the mix of the two.
In this case, you need to configure the formatting tool. This is specified in the name option of the tool item. The second option is the items where you can list the elements of the dropdown. The text defines the displayed label, and the value sets the type of element the item represents.
You can read more about this config option in the documentation here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/tools

I have followed your advice (Kendo for Vue, so code looks a little different)
tools: any = [
{ render: "Pop2FormatBlockTool", props: this.pop2FormatBlockToolSettings },
]
where:
pop2FormatBlockToolSettings: any = {
    ...EditorToolsSettings.formatBlock,
    items: [
        { text: this.kendoFormatBlockP, value: "p" },
        { text: this.kendoFormatBlockH1, value: "h1" },
    ]
}

But I still have two issues:  I cannot load $t translations to allow for multiple languages, and I cannot format "Heading 1" larger, as in English

Sorry for the jQuery example, I don't really know Vue. I don't see any viable solution for the formatting issue, not in the documentation, nor any class to set a css rule. As for the multi-language problem, can you specify the problem a bit more? I never did multi languages with Kendo, unfortunately.
